# Typescript generics use function params as optional

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to pipe an api call to a generic method.. I need to be able to deduce the params so I can type the dispatch method.

If I were to use the `Parameters<T[K]>` type, I will need to make the dispatch call with all the parameters like this `dispatcher.dispatch(["this is my data", ... ])` which is also not the main issue.

The main issue is that I cannot generically infer whether or not a parameter is optional.. so in the example below `dispatcher.dispatch()` breaks.

```
class Dispatcher<T extends object, K extends FunctionKeys<T>, P = T[K] extends (p1: infer P) => void ? P : never> {

    private readonly method: K;
    private readonly filter: (listener: any) => boolean;
    private readonly listenerResolver: () => any[];

    constructor(method: K, listenerResolver: () => any[]) {
        this.method = method;
        this.listenerResolver = listenerResolver;
        this.filter = (listener: any) => !!listener[this.method];
    }

    dispatch(arg: P) {
        const listeners = this.listenerResolver();
        listeners.filter(this.filter).forEach((listener: T) => listener[this.method](arg));
    }
}

interface Listener {
    action(data?: string): void;
}


const dispatcher = new Dispatcher<Listener, "action">("action", () => []);

dispatcher.dispatch("this is my data");
dispatcher.dispatch(); // this line does not compile
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create conditional type for arguments of `dispatch` method.
The full code (I replaced some types as your snippet was not complete:

```
class Dispatcher<T extends object, K extends keyof T, P = T[K] extends (p1: infer P) => void ? P : never> {

    private readonly method: K;
    private readonly filter: (listener: any) => boolean;
    private readonly listenerResolver: () => Record<K, Function>[];

    constructor(method: K, listenerResolver: () => Record<K, Function>[]) {
        this.method = method;
        this.listenerResolver = listenerResolver;
        this.filter = (listener: any) => !!listener[this.method];
  }
  // below solution
  dispatch(...arg: P extends undefined ? [] : [P]) {
      const listeners = this.listenerResolver();
      listeners.filter(this.filter).forEach((listener) => listener[this.method](arg));
  }
}

interface Listener {
    action(data?: string): void;
}


const dispatcher = new Dispatcher<Listener, "action">("action", () => []);

dispatcher.dispatch("this is my data");
dispatcher.dispatch(); // this line compiles :)
```

The solution is visible in `dispatch` method arguments type:

`...arg: P extends undefined ? [] : [P]`

We are saying that if `P` extends `undefined`, and optional property does, then arguments list is empty `[]`, so no arguments, but if there is an argument which is not optional, then it is required. Hope it helps.